# Mac OS X ldap Server connect to it from php

Tags: php, ldap, osx-server

Is it possible (I am trying) to connect to Mac OS X 10.6 server via php? My LDAP service is running.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    // using ldap bind
    $ldaprdn  = 'diradmin';     // ldap rdn or dn
    $ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("server.example.com")
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    ldap_set_option( $ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );

    if ($ldapconn) {

        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "LDAP bind successful...";
        } else {
            echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }

    }
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
Message: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid DN syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the following change in your code. This works for me with Mac OS X 10.5 Server. As far as I know 10.6 didn't really change much with regards to LDAP.

```
$ldaprdn="uid=diradmin,cn=users,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com";

// assumes ldap server is server.example.com
```

I highly recommend using LDAP Manager (for Mac) to view your OS X Server's LDAP Directory tree. [LDAP Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ldapmanager/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's a protocol problem. Try setting the protocol explicitely.
Something like:

```
ldap_set_option( $ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
```

Comment: No luck, but I turned off the firewall and got a different error message of Message: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid DN syntax.

Comment: So maybe your username is wrong... Should be something like "cn=admin, dc= ..."